# Blender 2.8 Wireframe Mode: show only visible Vertices

Tags: 3d-view, vertices, wireframe

As you see the back vertices are visible. I want them to be hidden as you would expect.
[image]

Comment: In the View panel try to decrease Clip End value. It worked in my case.

Comment: @kosin.ski...thanks for the CLIP END technique...this worked for me to hide vertices on the opposite face of an object I am weight painting. I'm really suprised that you can't simply select "Visible Vertices Only" option though - doesn't seem toe exist!

Answer (score 2):

In wireframe mode they used to be all visible but the "Show whole scene transparent" button changes between selecting visible only and selecting all. It's similar to the button I outlined in solid mode.

[image]

Comment: I think I dont have the outlined button. As you can seee on my 1. screenshot. Instead it displays a button called "show whole scene transparent". And this isnt what im looking for.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment. Click that "show whole scene transparent" button again and  it should do what you asked.

Comment: Hi, tried it and some other things. Doesnt work. I think its a bug,,,,

Comment: Don't know. It works on my a few weeks old build